# Execute CMD to open Remote Desktop in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So I am trying to use a `Button` to open a `CMD.exe` window to execute a command which allows me to automatically open a Remote Desktop with an IP from my network. I already built a piece of code, but it doesn't work. This is the code:

```
private void cmdRemote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "mstsc /v:" + txtIP.Text;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
}
```

I would like to know why it doesn't execute the command.

Comment: why run cmd.exe with a parameter, and not just run mstsc?  also, unhide the window and see what it says

Comment: Do you get any kind of error or it just does nothing?

Comment: Something like this `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "mstsc /v:IP");`? If I use it it will open a `cmd` window with my debug application path and does't do anything else. @BugFinder

Comment: @Rekcs correct because you havent told it to, youve used cmd.exe incorrectly, and if you had just run mstsc you probably would have had more success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add "/c" in front of your arguments list, else cmd won't execute it:

```
cmd /c mstsc /v:...
```

Or, why don't you call `mstsc` directly?

```
private void cmdRemote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "mstsc"
        Arguments = "/v:" + txtIP.Text
    }
    process.Start();
}
```

or shorter:

```
Process.Start("mstsc", "/v:" + this.txtIP.Text);
```

Don't forget to validate the value of `Text`!

Comment: Using it `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "mstsc /v:IP");`?

Comment: See edit. Or use the shorter `Process.Start("mstsc", "/v:" + txtIP.Text)`

Comment: Ok, it solved the problem. In conclusion, I don't need to call the `"cmd.exe"`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the cmd.exe, you can call the mstsc

```
 startInfo.FileName = "mstsc"
 startInfo.Arguments= " /v " + txtIP.Text
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Displays an error saying that was not possible to initialize the process because wasn't provided the file name.